# Are column families within a single keyspace related in any way?

Tags: cassandra

What's the difference between having keyspace Foo and column families A and B in it vs. having two keyspaces FooA and FooB with one column family in each?

API make it look as if these two were pretty much equivalent.

As a bonus question, how do supercolumns fit into this picture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Keyspace**: a namespace for ColumnFamilies, typically one per application. A keyspace is the first dimension of the Cassandra hash, and is the container for column families. Keyspaces are of roughly the same granularity as a schema or database (i.e. a logical collection of tables) in the RDBMS world. They are the configuration and management point for column families, and is also the structure on which batch inserts are applied.

**ColumnFamilies** contain multiple columns, each of which has a name, value, and a timestamp, and which are referenced by row keys.

**SuperColumns** can be thought of as columns that themselves have subcolumns (columnfamily within columnfamily).

A more fine grained explanation of the Cassandra data model is found [here](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DataModel)